# As kernel driver developer how can I know what IOCTLs and functions I should supply to Android?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, embedded, driver

http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/display_drivers.html

- accessing the driver by calling open on /dev/fb0
- using the  FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO and FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO Input / Output
  Control    (ioctl) calls to retrieve information about the screen
- using FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO ioctl to attempt to create a virtual
  display twice the size of the physical screen and to set the pixel
  format to rgb_565. If this succeeds, double buffering is accomplished
  with video memory.

Are there any more specific `IOCTLS` and functionality I need to introduce to Android as a kernel driver developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, text above requirements you have quoted clearly answers your question:

> Android makes **two** requirements of the driver: a linear address space
>   of mappable memory that it can write to directly and support for the
>   rgb_565 pixel format.

If you have some specific problems implementing this ioctl/functionality/etc, you are welcome to ask for support.